# Boxplot of pre-aggregated/grouped data in R

Tags: r, boxplot

In R I want to create a boxplot over count data instead of raw data.  So my table schema looks like 

Value | Count 
  1   |   2   
  2   |   1   
 
    ...

Instead of

Value 
  1   
  1   
  2   
 
    ...

Where in the second case I could simply do boxplot(x)

Comment: So what sort of graph are you expecting. That is just two count values and the boxplot is going to be pretty strange. Are you perhaps thinking of a barchart?

Comment: This is just example data, my real dataset has many more rows

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a way to do what you want with the already summarized data, but if not, you can abuse the fact that `rep` takes vectors:

```
> dat <- data.frame(Value = 1:5, Count = sample.int(5))
> dat
  Value Count
1     1     1
2     2     3
3     3     4
4     4     2
5     5     5
> rep(dat$Value, dat$Count)
 [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

Simply wrap boxplot around that and you should get what you want. I'm sure there's a more efficient / better way to do that, but this should work for you.

Comment: That works, but its very painful in my case because I wanted to do boxplots of multiple categories (in addition to Value, Count) in my plot.  But c'est la vie.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @John - no worries. My other suggestion would be to look at ggplot2. I know you can pass in pre-summarized data there. Sorry I don't use base graphics that often: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_boxplot.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue recently by using the 'apply' function on each column of counts with the 'rep' function:

```
> datablock <- apply(countblock[-1], 2, function(x){rep(countblock$value, x)})
> boxplot(datablock)
```

...The above assumes that your values are in the first column and subsequent columns contain count data.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `rep` and `data.frame` can be used as an approach if another variable is needed for classification

Eg.

```
with(data.frame(v1=rep(data$v1,data$count),v2=(data$v2,data$count)),
    boxplot(v1 ~ v2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Toy data:

(besides `Value` and `Count`, I add a categorical variable `Group`)

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(Value = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T),
                 Count = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
                 Group = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100, replace = T),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Use `purrr::pmap` and `purrr::reduce` to manipulate the data frame:

```
library(purrr)
data <- pmap(df, function(Value, Count, Group){
  data.frame(x = rep(Value, Count),
             y = rep(Group, Count))
}) %>% reduce(rbind)

boxplot(x ~ y, data = data)
```

[image]