# Creating boxplots in R using lattice for already processed data

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am trying to create a a boxplot in R of an extremely large data set. The file containing the data is 2.5G and crashes R if I try to import it. Fortunately some other piece of (python) software can generate the mean and variance without a problem, which is all I really want to plot(for now).

Every tutorial I've found so far requires you to input the full data set, then R computes the statistics itself, but I was wondering how to pass the mean, median, min, max, etc... to bwplot just for plotting. The reason I prefer R and lattice is because it integrates well with the software suite the code might end up in. If I used matlab or some other software that would be a problem because it would be yet another requirement from our current users.

Comment: If you're willing to using base graphics or ggplot, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7933268/324364) question may provide some ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boxplots do *not* plot mean or variance. You actually need the full ranked data to plot a proper boxplot, because the quantities are median, quartiles and the actual value of the closes data point within 1.5 times IRQ plus *all* data points that are outside that range (outliers). This is typically not a good idea for a large data set (because by definition you have millions of outliers).

That said, you can generate the essential summaries any way you want and use `bxp` to plot them - see `?bxp` in R. Just make sure you clarify what quantities you are plotting if they are not the above.

Comment: You are right, using only mean and variance isn't a boxplot and isn't the best thing to go on, but for now we just want to eyeball the data to see how it behave. bxp is exactly what I am looking for though. Thank you!