# Is there an efficient way to calculate percentiles from pre-aggregated data (R)?

Tags: r, percentile

First: This is my first question here and I'm relatively new to R, too. So, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or wrong way to ask.

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Website = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
             seconds = c(1,12,40,3,5,14),
             visitors = c(200000,100000,12000,250000,180000,90000))


> df
  Website seconds visitors
       A       1   200000
       A      12   100000
       A      40    12000
       B       3   250000
       B       5   180000
       B      14    90000
```

How to interpret the data: Website A has 200000 visitors who have been on the website for only 1 second, 100000 visitors for 12 seconds and so on.
In reality, the data has about hundred different websites, each with seconds ranging from 0 to about 900 (and a high number of visitors respectively).

Now, I want to calculate percentiles or at least quartiles for the visiting duration (for each website).

I already found and tried this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53882909
However, this solution is very inefficient as it results in a data frame with several million rows (and a very long processing time).

My question now: Is there a faster (more efficient way) to calculate percentiles from such pre-aggregated data?

Comment: Use a group-by function and use something like seconds[which.min(cumsum(visitors) >= sum(visitors) / 4)] to find the first quartile. I assume the data is sorted as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will be faster. First make a function to compute the quantiles you specify. Then split the data into a list and use `sapply`:

```
quant <- function(x, p=c(.25, .50, .75)) {
        v <- c(0, cumsum(x$visitors)/sum(x$visitors))
        s <- c(0, x$seconds)
        approx(v, s, p)$y
}
df.split <- split(df, df$Website)
p <- c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9)
stats <- t(sapply(df.split, quant, p=p))
colnames(stats) <- as.character(p)
round(stats, 1)
#   0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9
# A 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.8 0.9 3.0 6.5 9.9
# B 0.6 1.2 1.9 2.5 3.1 3.7 4.3 4.8 8.8
```

To see better what is going on here is a plot showing the data for Website A:

```
test1 <- df[1:3, ]
test1$cumvis <- cumsum(test1$visitors)
barplot(test1$seconds, test1$visitors, space=0, xlim=c(0, 325000))
axis(1, seq(0, 300000, 50000), c("0", "50K", "100K", "150K", "200K",
     "250K", "300K"), xpd=NA)
axis(3, seq(0, sum(test1$visitors), by=31200), seq(0, 1, by=.1), lty=1)
lines(c(0, test1$cumvis), c(0, test1$seconds), col="red", lwd=2)
lines(c(0, test1$cumvis-.5*test1$visitors, tail(test1$cumvis, 1)),
     c(0, test1$seconds, tail(test1$seconds,  1)), col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image: Plot for Website A]

The plot shows the data as grey rectangles. The bottom x-axis shows the cumulative number of visits and the top x-axis shows the cumulative proportion. We can treat the rectangles as the distribution or we can assume that the rectangles are a sample that approximates the underlying distribution. My suggested solution took the red line and used the `approx` function to use linear interpolation between the data points to estimate the number of seconds along that curve.

The same approach can be used with a different definition of the curve in which the data points are placed in the middle of each rectangle, the blue curve. I'll provide code for that approach as well. It is also possible to estimate the quantiles from the original data without replicating it.

First a function to estimate the quantiles along the blue line:

```
quant2 <- function(x, p=c(.25, .50, .75)) {
        v <- c(0, cumsum(x$visitors)-(.5*x$visitors)/sum(x$visitors), 1)
        s <- c(0, x$seconds, tail(x$seconds, 1))
        approx(v, s, p)$y
}
p <- c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9)
stats <- t(sapply(df.split, quant2, p=p))
colnames(stats) <- as.character(p)
round(stats, 1)
#   0.1 0.2  0.3  0.4 0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
# A 4.0 8.0 12.0 16.0  20 24.0 28.0 32.0 36.0
# B 1.4 2.8  4.2  5.6   7  8.4  9.8 11.2 12.6
```

The estimates are higher because the blue line is above the red line.

Finally, we can simply use the rectangles without any interpolation. Basically we set breaks at the boundaries of the data points and use those to identify which proportions fall in which groups of observations (seconds).

```
quant3 <- function(x, p=c(.25, .50, .75)){
    v <- c(0, cumsum(x$visitors)/sum(x$visitors))
    limits <- cut(p, breaks=v, include.lowest=TRUE, labels=x$seconds)
    limits <- as.numeric(as.character(limits))
}
p <- 0:10/10
stats <- t(sapply(df.split, quant3, p=p))
colnames(stats) <- as.character(p)
stats
#   0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1
# A 1   1   1   1   1   1   1  12  12  12 40
# B 3   3   3   3   3   5   5   5   5  14 14
```

So for website A, 1 second is the value for quantiles 0 - .6.

Comment: Thank you! This looks good at first. But I'm not sure approx() is appropriate with its linear interpolation. My data have many visitors during the first 30 seconds and significantly less afterwards (e.g., about 2  visitors on second 600).  So, I don't have a linear slope (if this is was approx assumes - I'm not sure).
Also one question for clarification: In row 1 you defined quartiles "p=c(.25, .50, .75)"  for the function and you later seem to "overwrite" them with defining a vector p with deciles (row 7).  Couldn't we just first define a percentile-vector and put this one into the function?

Comment: Thanks again for this great function! I now have tested your function with my real data. Approx() performs way better than I expected. Some deciles are wrong for 1-3 seconds, but I can live with that even though its not "perfect".
However, could you please explain in your own words what approx() actually does in your function? Just to help me understand how it works.
Also, I still don't understand why the first row defines quartiles while the 7th row redefines p as a vector of deciles.
Explanations to improve my understanding are very appreciated! :-)

Comment: I'll expand my answer to handle the first question. The `quant` function was defined with a default setting to compute quartiles, but you can pass a different set to the function if you want, in the example deciles. If you run the `stats <- t(sapply(df.split, quant)`, you will get the quartiles.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your extended answer and explanations. That is extremely helpful and appreciated! Just FYI: quant2 didn't work with my real data very well. The over-estimation is huge. But I might have translated your function incorrectly to my real setting, so this might be my fault. Anyway: quant3 applies best to my data. I agree that approx() is a nice solution for such data like in my example (which probably wasn't a good example). For my real data, your function quant3 gives the best representation of the underlying distribution.